# $f:A\to B,\,B_1\subset B, f^{-1}(B\setminus B_1)=A\setminus f^{-1}(B_1)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$f:A\to B,\,B_1\subset B,\,f^{-1}(\cdot)$ is the pre-image and want to show below

$$f^{-1}(B\setminus B_1)=A\setminus f^{-1}(B_1)$$

Below is my attempt proof, and I am aiming for a **Fully** detailed process, and I also re-realised not abusing the preimage notation. Appreciate any comments and looking for a neater one.

$\implies$

let $x\in f^{-1}(B\setminus B_1)$, there exists a $y=f(x)\in B \setminus B_1$, which means $y\in B 
 \land y\notin B_1.$ For arbitrary union $\bigcup\{y\}\subset B\setminus B_1$, the corresponding pre-image has to be $f^{-1}(B\setminus B_1)= \color{red}{\{x\in A|f(x)\in B \land f(x)\notin B_1\}=\{x\in A\setminus f^{-1}(B_1)| f(x)\in B\}}$

I know that in order to prove two sets to be equal require both sets are subset of each other, but please look at the red part only, I think this is straight out from the definition. Can set do this operation, If not, why?

If such operation is allowed, it's awkward to say $\,\forall x\in f^{-1}(B\setminus B_1),\, x\in A\setminus f^{-1}(B_1)$, then $f^{-1}(B\setminus B_1)\subset A\setminus f^{-1}(B_1)$, because the red equality holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the red equation, your operation is OK. As you wrote, this question may be too easy once you understand pre-images of maps.

Here is my (formal and detailed) proof:

For all $x\in A$,
\begin{align}
x\in f^{-1}(B\setminus B_1)
&\Longleftrightarrow f(x)\in B\setminus B_1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow f(x)\notin B_1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x\notin f^{-1}(B_1)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x\in A\setminus f^{-1}(B_1).
\end{align}
Hence the two sets are equal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My confusion comes from experience, isn't the sets to be proved equal has to prove they are a subset of each other?

Comment: Yes! That is true. I used the fact that the following are equivalent: (1) $A=B$, i.e., $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$. (2) for all $x$, $x\in A\Longleftrightarrow x\in B$.